# Setting a custom variable in Google Analytics after _trackPageview is called

Tags: google-analytics

Using Goggle Analytics I'd like to use a custom variable.  This is built in functionality, but unfortunately I don't have control over the code that loads GA and calls _trackPageview;

This means I can't call _setCustomVar before _trackPageview

If I call _trackPageview a second time will it log two page views?

For example

```
// I'm not able to change this order
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

// I'm forced to run this after the first _trackPageview
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'name','value']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Is there any other way to get the custom variable set

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, each _trackPageview will log a page view.

You could pass a pageURL to the second _trackPageview, and set a filter in your analytics profile to ignore those page views.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/dummyPageName']);
```

Alternatively, instead of a second _trackPageview, you could use _trackEvent to cause a tracking GIF request and deliver the custom variable.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'name', 'value']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'dummy category', 'dummy action']);
```

Comment: This actually the recommended method in such situations

Comment: Does the filtering of '/dummyPagename' not filter out all custom variables associated with that utm.gif request?

Comment: @TomFuertes Good point! I suspect you're right, but I'm going to give it a test.

Comment: @mike :) looking forward to a follow up!

Answer (score 4):

In order to prevent affecting the statistics on both your page view count and your bouncerate you should probably use the _trackEvent method and remember to set the opt_noninteraction variable to false. This should neither track a page view nor affect the bouncerate

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'name', 'value']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'label', 1, true]);
```

Comment: Are you sure about it not tracking the page view? Do you have a link for it?

Comment: Yes, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide
It states about the last parameter in _trackEvent: "A boolean that when set to true, indicates that the event hit will not be used in bounce-rate calculation.

Comment: Furthermore, on that same page it says "pageview calculations are unaffected by user activity tracked using the Event Tracking method."

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, and it seems the better solution is to move `_setCustomVar` BEFORE `_trackPageview` is called. You're going to have to initiate the `_gaq` variable prior to the `_setCustomVar` like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'name','value',3]);
```